# getting error while fetching full data with my python function?

Tags: python, api, python-3.6

I am trying to fetch product data from an api.

By default this api returns 20 products and in a single request the api can return max 500 products if we use api's parameter Limit=500.

So for fetching all products we need to use one more parameter with Limit- Offset(Number of products to skip).

I have written following function to achieve this but in case of full data my function is not working well and it's giving me error like- Login failed, Signature mismatching.

```
def get_data(userid, api_key, action, pagination=True):
    timeformat = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + '+08:00'
    endpoint = 'https://example.com'
    page_json = {}
    # set required parameters for this api
    parameters = {
      'UserID': userid,
      'Version': '1.0',
      'Action': action,
      'Format': 'JSON',
      'Timestamp': timeformat
    }
    if pagination:
        page = 0
        parameters['Limit'] = 500
        while True:
            parameters['Offset'] = 500 * page
            # set the required cryptographic signature
            concatenated = urllib.parse.urlencode(sorted(parameters.items()))
            parameters['Signature'] = HMAC(api_key, concatenated.encode('utf-8'), sha256).hexdigest()
            page += 1
            try:
                response = requests.get(endpoint, params=parameters)
                page_json = response.json()
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                print("Connection refused!")
                sleep(5)
    else:
        try:
            concatenated = urllib.parse.urlencode(sorted(parameters.items()))
            # set the required cryptographic signature
            parameters['Signature'] = HMAC(api_key, concatenated.encode('utf-8'), sha256).hexdigest()
            response = requests.get(endpoint, params=parameters)
            page_json = response.json()
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print("Connection refused!")
            sleep(5)

 return page_json
```

It looks like I am not fitting my signature parameter line correctly in case of full data.I printed the value of `concatenated` and it looks like-

page is  1
concatenated:: Action=GetProducts&Format=JSON&Limit=500&Offset=500&Signature=3d9cd320a4bf816aeea828b9392ed2d5a27cd584b3a337338909c0ab161a101e&Timestamp=2018-05-26T12%3A58%3A38%2B08%3A00&UserID=contact%40example.com.sg&Version=1.0
try: {'ErrorResponse': {'Head': {'ErrorCode': '7', 'ErrorMessage': 'E7:Login failed. Signature mismatching', 'ErrorType': 'Sender', 'RequestAction': 'GetProducts', 'RequestId': '0bb606c015273197313552686ec46f'}}}

page is  2
concatenated:: Action=GetProducts&Format=JSON&Limit=500&Offset=1000&Signature=c1bda1a5ab21c4e4182cc82ca7ba87cb9fc6c5f24c36f9bb006f9da906cf7083&Timestamp=2018-05-26T12%3A58%3A38%2B08%3A00&UserID=contact%40example.com.sg&Version=1.0
try: {'ErrorResponse': {'Head': {'ErrorCode': '7', 'ErrorMessage': 'E7:Login failed. Signature mismatching', 'ErrorType': 'Sender', 'RequestAction': 'GetProducts', 'RequestId': '0bb606c015273197321748243ec3a5'}}}

Can you please look into my function and help me to find out what I have written wrong and what it should be like?

Comment: I think you are using the same dict that contains Signature in your loop, so the first request goes OK, but the subsequent ones fail because the signature is wrong. Try printing `concatenated` on every iteration.

Comment: Yes it is happening actually-

Comment: @Norrius..I have added printed value. Since we are setting Offset different for every request,the signature will also be changed. So what's your point here?

Comment: Please have a look into my code and let me know how can I make it right?

Comment: Seeing that you calculate signature based on `concatenated`, I don't think the previous iteration's signature should be in that dict.

Comment: @Norrius..I have printed signature and it's changing in every request.So it means I am not passing same signature every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
if pagination:
    page = 0
    parameters['Limit'] = 500
    while True:
        parameters['Offset'] = 500 * page
        # set the required cryptographic signature
        concatenated = urllib.parse.urlencode(sorted(parameters.items()))
        parameters['Signature'] = HMAC(api_key, concatenated.encode('utf-8'), sha256).hexdigest()
        page += 1
        try:
            response = requests.get(endpoint, params=parameters)
            page_json = response.json()
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print("Connection refused!")
            sleep(5)
        del parameters['Signature']
```

Comment: Thanks @Norrus. It's helpful.